# How to open an application with its window maximized?

Tags: python, windows

```
import os
import win32gui, win32con

class Path:
   pass

path1 = os.popen(r"C:\Windows\notepad.exe")
```

Once the notepad is open, it should appear with full screen(maximize window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you launched the executable using *os.popen*, @zwer answer (using [[Python.Docs]: subprocess - Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)) is the nicest way of doing things.
However, since you're also using *PyWin32*, here's an alternative that uses [[MS.Learn]: CreateProcessW function (processthreadsapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) (via its wrapper: [[GitHub.MHamond]: win32process.CreateProcess](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32/win32process__CreateProcess_meth.html)).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import win32con as wcon
import win32process as wproc


EXE_NAME = r"C:\Windows\notepad.exe"


def main(*argv):
    si = wproc.STARTUPINFO()
    si.dwFlags = wcon.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    si.wShowWindow = wcon.SW_MAXIMIZE
    h_proc, h_thr, pid, tid = wproc.CreateProcess(None, EXE_NAME, None, None, False, 0, None, None, si)
    print(h_proc, h_thr, pid, tid)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050718126> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> <PyHANDLE:556> <PyHANDLE:552> 11952 14144
> ```

**and** the *Notepad* window pops up maximized :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to also mark the answer as a solution (if it solved your problem).

Answer (score 4):

You can use Windows's `start` command with a `/max` modifier, i.e.:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "start", "/max", "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"])
```

Comment: What are the arguments for this call?

Comment: @Snedecor - What do you mean?