# How do I launch an application maximised with python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a toggle button to launch/close steam games, however, I want the games to start in fullscreen mode.

`subprocess.call` and the steam app ID allows launching the game and
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718126/how-to-open-an-application-with-its-window-maximized) link mentioned using a `/max` modifier, i.e.:

```
def start():
    subprocess.call(["/max",r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe -applaunch 378760"])
```

However that gave me the error `TypeError: bufsize must be an integer`. I checked [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and `subprocess.call` expects a `list` of arguments, not multiple arguments. So I added the `[]` to give it a list and now I get the error; `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

The `/max` modifer works for non-steam games i.e. it worked fine for notepad.

**What do I need to do to get this to work for steam games?**

Answer (score -1):

`/max` is an argument for the cmd to start an application, not steam.
Your row of arguments to subprocess is also in the wrong order. First comes the call (in your case to Steam) and then its arguments.

Steam has its own flag. See this [Documentation](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/7D01-D2DD-D75E-2955)

for you the modifier `-fullscreen` is relevant.

try this:

```py
def start():
    subprocess.call([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe","-applaunch"," 378760","-fullscreen"])
```

Comment: Issue is those steam flags are optional, the game needs to be encoded to make use of them and most annoyingly aren't.

Comment: Interestingly that does open steam, it doesn't maximise it. It just activates the window and moves it to the foreground, but not the given game.

Comment: `"-applaunch"` and `"378760"` also need to be two distinct arguments, properly speaking. Windows might hide this bug, but it's still a bug.

Comment: Launches it, but -fullscreen doesn't work annoyingly. Probably because the app in question doesn't support the flags.